# tikz node name and calculation

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, pgfmath

I can't find out why the following code :

```
\documentclass[border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart, fit,backgrounds,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(poste1){poste};
\foreach\x in {1,...,5}{%
\pgfmathparse{\x+1}
\node[right=of poste\x](poste\pgfmathresult){poste\pgfmathresult};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

doesn't work.
With this code

```
\documentclass[border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart, fit,backgrounds,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(poste1){poste};
\foreach\x in {1}{%
\pgfmathparse{\x+1}
\node[right=of poste\x](poste\pgfmathresult){poste\pgfmathresult};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

it appears that the `\pgfmathresult` command return a wrong number hence the error but I don't know why this occurs.
Could somebody help me please?

Comment: `\pgfmathresult` probably returns something like `1.9999997` instead of `2`. Have you tried `\pgfmathparse{int(\x+1)}`. If that also fails, set an integer macro and use it's value: `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\myNext{\x+1}
\node[right=of poste\x](poste\myNext){poste\myNext};`

Comment: @Tom, can you transform your comment in answer? I like to see, how to use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\myNext{\x+1}`, as `\pgfmathparse{int(\x+1)}` fails in all my tests.

Comment: In your first listing, simply replace `\pgfmathparse{\x+1}
\node[right=of poste\x](poste\pgfmathresult){poste\pgfmathresult};` with `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myNext}{\x+1} \node[right=of poste\x](poste\myNext){poste\myNext};`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simpler than use of `\pgfmathparse` is:

```
\documentclass[border=0mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{%backgrounds,calc,fit,
                positioning,
                %shapes.multipart
                }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance= 2mm]
\node (poste1) {poste1};
\foreach \x [count=\xx from 2] in {1,2,...,5}
{
\node[right=of poste\x] (poste\xx) {poste \xx};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can use a simple `evaluate=` as this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart, fit,backgrounds,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(poste1){poste1};
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \y using int(\x-1)] in {2,...,6}{%
\node[right=of poste\y](poste\x){poste\x};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives the correct result:

[image]

The reasons why your example doesn't work are as follows:

1. The `\pgfmathparse` command evaluates to a floating point number (2.0, 3.0, etc).
2. You should use the `\pgfmathresult` immediately after its `\pgfmathparse`.
3. For reason 2, you can define a new macro `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\y{\x+1}`, as suggested by @TomBombadil in a comment, and replace each `\pgfmathresult` with `\y`.

Comment: Do you think it altogether fair to edit your answer an hour after another was posted to use the method from that answer without even crediting that answer? You were using `evaluate` and the other answer `count` which is simpler. An hour later, you changed yours to use `count` without acknowledging that this method was used by the other answer.

Comment: @cfr  - Here is the original solution again. BTW, I didn't try to copy the other answer, I almost forgot that the `count=` method was used above (and I used it differently) and I do acknowledge other people (you see, I mentioned TomBombadil when I talked about his idea).

Comment: You could use your version of the `count` code and just link to the other answer as similar. I didn't mean you were copying, but just that, since the other answer was posted first and this is the same question, I think it is courteous/fairer to explicitly acknowledge that. It may well just have been an oversight on your part - that is extremely easy to do, goodness knows, and I do it myself.

Comment: I think you should make clear what *immediately after* means.  The OP may think that's what he/she is doing.  I'd phrase it as, "save `\pgfmathresult` to command control sequence before doing **anything** else in TikZ".