# Tikz - Dynamic Node Naming

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-node

I need to dynamically create the ids of the nodes in TiKz with a counter, so that I can position the new nodes in terms of the previous ones. The counter is created as follows and gets increased for each new node:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newcounter{nojobs}\setcounter{nojobs}{0}
```

The definition of the command that creates the TiKz node dynamically is the following one (this command can get invoked as many times as required):

```
\newcommand{\job}[7]{
    \stepcounter{nojobs}

    \node [
        regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides=3,
        fill=headergray,
        anchor=north,
        shift={(+0.0cm,+0.0cm)},
        minimum width=\tipheight,
        minimum height=\tipheight,
        shape border rotate=90
    ]
        (__job_\value{nojobs})
        at
        (__job_\the\numexpr\value{nojobs}-1\relax.south)
    {};

}
```

The problem is that, whenever the command is invoked, LaTeX says:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\job ...par \par \stepcounter {nojobs} \par \node
```

- Is this the correct approach for the problem? Any alternative solutions?
- Can the counter variable be used in this way?
- Can the counter variable be decreased and used in the calculation of the previous node ID?

Comment: Please make your code snippets compilable ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach works -- in principle. Here are the first steps to make it work. The only real "improvement" is the use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning,backgrounds,shapes}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newcounter{nojobs}\setcounter{nojobs}{0}
\newcommand{\job}[7]{
    \stepcounter{nojobs}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ni}{\value{nojobs}}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nj}{\value{nojobs}-1}
    \node 
    [
        regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides=3,
%        fill=headergray,
        anchor=north,
        shift={(+0.0cm,+0.0cm)},
%         minimum width=\tipheight,
%         minimum height=\tipheight,
        shape border rotate=90
    ]
        (jobnode\ni)
        at
        (jobnode\nj.south)
    {#1};

}
\begin{document}
\tikz{\node (jobnode0) at (0,0) {};\job1234567\job2345678}
\end{document}
```

My crystal ball broke, so I had to comment out some of the options which one does not know without a compilable MWE.

EDIT: I cut of the `.0` in the floating point numbers returned in an earlier version of my answer, using the comments to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279059/tikz-node-name-and-calculation?rq=1).

Comment: Why truncate `\value{nojobs}`? It's a counter: it must be an integer. You wouldn't need truncate at all if you saved the value before and after stepping the counter.

Comment: @cfr Because with my previous version, in which I used \pgfmathsetmacro, the nodes had names ending with 0.0, 1.0 etc. See the discussion following [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279059/tikz-node-name-and-calculation?rq=1).

Comment: Yes, but you don't need `\pgfmathsetmacro` here. PGFMATH is really, really expensive. You're using it completely unnecessarily.

Comment: @cfr OK, if you have a better answer, I'll be happy to withdraw mine. (I was under the impression that the original MWE does not work simply because `\value{nojob}` does not work when labeling tikz nodes.)

Comment: This has always been my biggest struggle with LaTeX: not being 100% aware of when one 'control sequence' will work within a given environment or not.

Comment: `\thenojobs` would work, though. Just set e.g. `\ni` to `\thenojobs`, step the counter and set `\nj` in the same way. You don't need pgfmath for this.

Comment: @cfr Thanks, I did not know. Similarly to Ricardo, I fail to understand which command works in a given environment. Is there a document explaining this?

Comment: @marmot `\value{}` isn't for printing anything. You need e.g. `\arabic{}` or whatever for that. I assume the TeX Book should cover `\value{}`. Any introduction to LaTeX should cover counters. There's nothing specific to Ti*k*Z here.

Comment: @marmot Try `
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{1}
\value{mycounter}
a
\themycounter
b
\arabic{mycounter}
c
\end{document}` and note that you get an error.